# How to scroll one page at a time in Asterisk at the command line?

Tags: linux, asterisk

Asterisk has a command line shell mode which I enter by typing `asterisk -r` at the linux command line.

Inside its shell the standard linux commands like `| more` or `| less` do not work.  And the screen just whizzes past me with no way of scrolling back up that I know of.

However, I can't be the first person that has this issue.  Solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page-Up</kbd>? It is the common way of getting back in the scroll buffer of your console. That might not be the perfect solution but you should be able to get to any point in the log you want to. Note that most consoles allow you to set how many lines of buffer to keep. So you can increase it in case it is not enough for you purpose.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it had no effect on the screen whatsoever.

Comment: For me it works. How do you access the console / which terminal are you using? Are you running asterisk -r within a screen session? If you do see Darth Android's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try running it from inside of a `screen` session. It supports scrolling back through the log with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>[</kbd>. Because `screen` functions as a virtual terminal, `asterisk` need not have support for it.